# Can C# Winstore app access email app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps

I want specifically to be able to search through emails stored on the local device using C# Winstore (Metro) app.

Consider an application which need to find if a certain text is present in the emails stored on this particular Windows 8 device (eg with built-in Mail application) to make a decision.

Is there a some kind of passive share contract (which can be invoked from another application) ?

**or**

to be able to invoke a remote command to make Mail application to search it for the application in question and return result (something like .NET Remoting)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is bring up the Search pane with [SearchPane.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225096.aspx) and seed the proper query.  The user would need to select the Mail app from the Search pane in order to compete the search.  The user could then select data in an email and Share it back to you (if you are a Share target).  There is no way for one Store style app to access the data stored in the local storage of another.

Per comment:  Make sure you have the proper Search declaration in your manifest.  You can add that with the [Manifest Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230259%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Declarations).  Then you can call SearchPane.Show as follows ...

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchPane.GetForCurrentView().Show("Foo");
```